# Lock screen effect on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, locking, lockscreen

I would like to ask if it would be possible to emulate the lock ripple effect (in the lockscreen) inside an app.
I need this effect for displaying it in the touch event. It is very similar to the incoming call effect.
Is there an easy way? Do I need to create a custom effect?

Thank You.

Edit:
I found the ic_lockscreen_handle_normal.png file for implementing the lock, but I'm not able to find where it's used. What's the file for the lockscreen handle?

Comment: Android is open source you know. You can simply look at how it is created in the lockscreen.

Comment: I'm new to Android. Where can I look at the lock related source code?

Answer (score 0):

yea lot of projects which does this,
for example you could use the following project which enables the water ripple effect
https://code.google.com/p/waterrippleeffect/